# Is there a way to add different Id's to multiple elements with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have

```
<iframe> id="iframeid"
<div> </div>
<div> </div>
<div> </div>
<div> </div>
</iframe>
```

Is there a way to add unique Id's to the divs using javascript?
For example

```
<iframe> id="iframeid"
<div>id="divid1"</div>
<div>id="divid2" </div>
<div>id="divid3" </div>
<div>id="divid4" </div>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Sure, though you *probably* don't want to do that. Why are you adding unique IDs to the divs?

Comment: IDs meant to be *unique* i.e. only one element may have an ID. In this case, you should use classes instead.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum So that I can change them one by one not all of them at once

Comment: @FZs Oh I'm trying to give a different id to each div. I'm sorry if I haven't worded my question correctly, english isn't my main language

Comment: @AzzazzinsCreed Neither is mine. Assigning different IDs is OK. However, you should provide a bit more details about how (and based on what) should the IDs added.

Comment: @FZs Thanks for the advice, I changed it. Hope it's better now

Comment: [Off-topic]: Your HTML syntax is invalid (a tag's attributes should be before the closing `>`): `<div>id="divid1"</div>` should be `<div id="divid1"> </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return all the div elements with `document.getElementsByTagName`. This return a NodeList (of div in this case) that you can access with bracket notation (or item method, it's the same) that return the Element Node. You can set its attribute id with `.id=value` or `setAttribute(id,value)`. In my example I set the div elements with `id=id0    id=id1`  and so on.

```
      let myDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
      for(let i=0 ; i<myDivs.length ;i++)
         myDivs[i].id = `id${i}`;
```

Furthermore note that `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` returns all the div in the page,  if you want only the div of an element, for instance an iframe element with `id=myiframe` you can do:

```
document.getElementById("myiframe").getElementsByTagName("div");
```

Also note that this method detects all the div in the subtree, it is not limited to direct children

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'd vote your answer but my reputation is less than 15.

Comment: No problem. Also note in your example that you have to put the id attribute inside the tag.  i.e. <div id="id1"></div> instead of <div >id="id1"</div>